# Extensive String Manipulation - Cursor or While-Loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, cursor

**Quick Background**

I have received a project from our marketing team to make bulk updates to the descriptions of products that will be displayed on our website (>500k items). They have decided to take many decades worth of descriptions and try to make them as similar as possible. (Ex. 'screw driver', 'screwdriver', 'screw-driver' should all look like 'Screwdriver')

I successfully accomplished the task at hand to 95% of their satisfaction using a clunky, long and hard to maintain series of update statements on a table only I maintain, to modify the strings. I then pass these on to our web deployment team, but wasn't thinking they would want to maintain this indefinitely.

I can easily produce a table of sub-strings and conditions to find and what to replace portions of the string. I think something depending on a table like this would be easiest to maintain for 90% of the cases we encounter.

Now, I'm uncertain about the best way to proceed to make this dependable and easy to maintain. I've received conflicting information that a good use would be a 'while loop' and other say a Cursor would be just fine.

**Now to the question**

Given we will/may/could be adding somewhere around 1k new products a month, and I have a table of conditions like the following, what is the most efficient and dependable way to execute the manipulation regularly?

---

Condition, Find_substring, Replace_with

---

like '%screw driver%', 'screw driver', 'Screwdriver'

---

like '%screw-driver%', 'screw driver', 'Screwdriver'

---

like '%screwdriver%', 'screwdriver', 'Screwdriver'

**Open to any and all ideas, suggestions and advice.**

Comment: Have you tried CLR stored procedure

Comment: There really isn't a need for any looping here at all. I assume you have a list of "bad" values and the "good" value you want it to be updated too.

Comment: Yes, I have a list of the Good and the bad values. Ideally I may make both a function to be called for single products being added to 'scrub' the descriptions as they are added 1 at a time AND a stored procedure to update a table when we do bulk additions.

Comment: You have a third technical option which is using recursive CTEs.  However, I would be careful.  My gut reaction is that putting the descriptions in Excel and hiring an intern might be a good solution.  Be very careful about the unintended side effects of blind replacement, as described by @TomH.

Comment: Hah. Interns. I wish we had interns... I'll look into this suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rules are really as simple as that then simply having "old_value" and "new_value" in the table should suffice, with a single statement to fix all of the data:

```
UPDATE
    MT
SET
    description = REPLACE(description, old_value, new_value)
FROM
    dbo.My_Table MT
INNER JOIN dbo.Fix_Table FT ON MT.description LIKE '%' + FT.old_value + '%'
```

You might need to adjust the query if you expect multiple matches on a single product. Also, be careful of strings that might be part of another string. For example, fixing "ax" to "axe" might cause problems with a "fax machine". There are a lot of little details like this that might affect the exact approach.

Comment: I had talked myself out of something like this at some point, but it really is pretty simple and easy to maintain. I specifically posted because I was looking for a single approach to also take care of some of the more complex strings, but I might just have to accept those will need to be done by hand.

Comment: This only works for replacing one value, not for replacing multiple values.

Comment: Yes, that was why I said, "You might need to adjust the query if you expect multiple matches on a single product."

Answer (score 1):

Have a table like bad_val and good_val (call it tblMod). you can write a stored procedure that loops on tblMod and generate SQL statement and execute the statement as dynamic SQL.

```
loop on tblMod
-- generate SQL statements like:
set sqlText = 'update myTable set description = ' + good_val + ' where description = ' + bad_val
sp_execute sqlText
```

This approach also allows you to use SQL functions or any other functions in good_val field of tblMod. for instance you can have below data in good_val field: 'upper(description)' 
or 'substring(description, 1 ,4)'

as you are generating dynamic SQL, those will work.
in this case your sqlText will be something like

```
'update myTable set description = substring(description, 1, 4) where description = 'some bad value'
```

example above might not be correct but I hope you get my idea.